# Splitting of data across blkxxxxx.dat files

Tags: bitcoin-core, block, blockchain-data-storage

I am trying to parse out the bitcoin data using Big Data and wanted to know more about the blk files themselves. I was wondering how does bitcoin split the transactions across the files. I know there is a 128 MiB limit on the files. Does that mean it is possible for transaction data to be split across a blk ? For instance the merkle root of the transaction is in one file and the output index is in another ? Or is block data retained in a single file ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Blocks are never split across files: the whole block, from magic to length, to header, to transaction data, is always stored in a single file, continuously.

However you may need to take into account:

- Blocks in the blk*.dat files are stored in the order they are received from the network.l, which may not be the blocks' logical order.
- It is possible that a block is in file N, and its descendant block is in file N-1.
- The files contain all blocks ever received, including ones that are not part of the main chain but were reorged out.
- There can be "gaps" of zeroes or garbage data between blocks in the blk*.dat files.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Just one follow up, is there anyway we can pre-sort the blk files in anyway ? Because I'd like to process them into a CSV on individual nodes on a distributed environment and then find out the input address by looking backwards if that makes sense

Comment: Bitcoin Core has a linearize script: https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/tree/master/contrib/linearize. This can be used to construct a single file with all blocks in the active chain (no reorged forks), in order, without gaps.

Answer (score 0):

As a kind of addendum to the first bullet-point in [Pieter's answer](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/114743/13866), I had written a program to parse `blkxxxxx.dat` files and, in my case at least, the blocks are very obviously *not* in logical order. Just as Pieter asserted.

Notice the day number in the timestamps in the first ten blocks:

```
C> blockchain -file blk02100.dat -blocks -longstats
Block      1, 2020-06-03 03:48, target 171297F6,   2273 transactions
Block      2, 2020-06-03 04:29, target 171297F6,   2768 transactions
Block      3, 2020-06-04 02:00, target 171297F6,   2177 transactions
Block      4, 2020-06-05 12:37, target 17147F35,   2243 transactions
Block      5, 2020-06-01 07:15, target 171297F6,   3150 transactions
Block      6, 2020-06-02 21:48, target 171297F6,   2911 transactions
Block      7, 2020-06-02 21:49, target 171297F6,   2722 transactions
Block      8, 2020-06-05 16:23, target 17147F35,    182 transactions
Block      9, 2020-06-03 05:34, target 171297F6,   2002 transactions
Block     10, 2020-06-03 04:36, target 171297F6,   1958 transactions
...
Block    111, 2020-06-06 03:39, target 17147F35,    259 transactions

Statistics for blk02100.dat (2020-06-01 to 2020-06-06)

   111 blocks
222519 transactions (2004.7 per block)
109173 Segwit tx    (49.1%)
622026 inputs       (mean 2.8, max 1030 per transaction)
614553 outputs      (mean 2.8, max 3799 per transaction)

Processed file in 322.5756ms
```

I guess this scattered order is because my node was receiving blocks from multiple peers and concurrently receiving them from fairly disjoint ranges.

I can confirm that every `blkxxxxx.dat` file I tried, started and ended at a block boundary. There were no partial blocks.

---

Footnote: My program isn't extensively tested so maybe take the above with a pinch of salt. I believe the timestamps to be parsed correctly.

Comment: Yes ! I have found the same to be true and the python parser i am currently using [parser](https://github.com/alecalve/python-bitcoin-blockchain-parser) also has the option to obtain blocks in an ordered/ unordered form.